# Input string not in Correct format error while using the Google currency Conversion API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My application is in Asp.Net MVC3 coded in C#.Net.
Im using google Currency Conversion API for getting the conversion.

[Google Currency Conversion API](http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?GBP) 
Im passing the **From Currency** and **To Currency** values and the amount to my Controller.
Below is my C# code.

```
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={2}{0}%3D%3F{1}", CurrenctCurr.ToUpper(), DestinationCurr.ToUpper(), TotCurrentPay);
    string response = web.DownloadString(url);
    Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*.\\d*)");
    Match match = regex.Match(response);
    decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Im getting an error on line

```
decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
```

The error is **Input string not in Correct format**.There is no inner exception to it.

I tried it to convert to toString()

```
   decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
```

Also i tried to take the value of **match** in a string variable and then try doing a SubString logic on it.But its not working either

```
string test = match.ToString();
test=test.substring(0,test.Indexof("""));
```

There is a single Quotation ("),so im trying to take the value of string till ".
Suggest how can i solve the issue.Or what else can i try in the right direction.

Comment: What is the value of `match.Groups[1].Value`?

Comment: can you give the values you are passing  CurrenctCurr.ToUpper(), DestinationCurr.ToUpper(), TotCurrentPay

Comment: The same code work perfectly for me with following values     CurrenctCurr = "USD";
DestinationCurr = "GBP";
TotCurrentPay = "10.123";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for getting url.

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={2}{0}%3D%3F{1}", CurrenctCurr.ToUpper(), DestinationCurr.ToUpper(), TotCurrentPay));
    string url = uri.AbsoluteUri + uri.Fragment;
    string response = web.DownloadString(url);
```